# Redux, MapStateToProps/useSelector: Is it safe to mutate those values

Tags: react-redux, mapstatetoprops

Both MapStateToProps and useSelector work with similiar callback `store => store.group`
Is it safe to mutate those values for example in MapStateToProps like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = store => {
  const { group, level } = store;
  let { group } = store;
  if (level > 50) {
    group = `${group}-admin`;
  }
  return { group };
};
```

or in useSelector:

```
const group = useSelector(store => {
  const { group, level } = store;
  let { group } = store;
  if (level > 50) {
    group = `${group}-admin`;
  }
  return { group };
});
```

And with useSelector it could actually be done inside the component too like this:

```
let [group, level] = useSelector(store => [store.group, store.level);
if (level > 50) {
  group = `${group}-admin`;
}
...
```

My co-worker did something like this and I'm not sure if you are supposed to use `let` in there. I'm just interested if that is acceptable way to deal with this or if that causes problems? I don't need a different solution for it. I know how to do it with using `const`instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the roles of `redux` is to centralize your `state` logic:

From: https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

> The whole state of your app is stored in an object tree inside a single store. **The only way to change the state tree is to emit an action, an object describing what happened.** To specify how the actions transform the state tree, you write pure reducers.

So when you do something like this:

```
const group = useSelector(store => {
  const { group, level } = store;
  let { group } = store;
  if (level > 50) {
    group = `${group}-admin`;
  }
  return { group };
});
```

This should be considered bad practice. The `useSelector` hook should return a piece of your state without mutating it. You are mutating it inside the `useSelector` call, so you are returning something that maybe not in the `state` object.

From `node_modules/react-redux/src/hooks/useSelector.js`:

[image]

See that they even name the result of `selectedState = selector(storeState)` as `selectedState`. And you are not selecting a `state` on your call. You are mutating the result.

While in your example you are just mutating a string that you read from the `state`, this is a bad practice because one day you might mutate the `state` object without mutating it through an `action/reducer` dispatch. Which would definitely break your code at some point.

For example:

```
const group = useSelector((state) => {
  let { someObject } = state;
  if (someCondition) {
    someObject.someProperty = someValue  // YOU ARE MUTATING STATE OUTSIDE A REDUX REDUCER
  }
  return someObject;
});
```

What I think you should do:

**SomeComponent.js**

```
const { group, level } = useSelector((state) => state);
const newGroup = level > 50 ? `${group}-admin` : group;
```

If what you want instead is to update the `group` state property on Redux, you should instead dispatch an action to be handled by a reducer.